# It takes a while for my MacBook to recognize keyboard presses and trackpad clicks upon wake

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, catalina, mouse, trackpad

Sometimes it takes over a minute for my MacBook Pro 16 inch to recognize anything I write on the keyboard and whatever I do with the trackpad upon waking it up from sleep mode. In fact, sometimes it will say it doesn't detect a keyboard and it expects me to insert or pair a keyboard. After a couple minutes the problem disappears, however.

I've done PRAM/NVRAM as well as SMC procedures. Still having the same problem. I've also booted in safe mode. No result.

Comment: Have you tried the normal troubleshooting steps [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)?

Comment: Thanks. I've just reset the NVRAM. Do you think I should also do the SMC?

Comment: If that didn't solve problem then yes, you should do that.

Comment: Boot into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262), allow or put it to sleep, then wake. See if the problem persists.

Comment: The keyboard (or whole top case) may be failing.  However, it's plugged into the USB bus.  To eliminate USB as the issue, plug in a USB keyboard and see if you still have the problem.  If you do, it's a physical problem with the top case and you need to take it in to be fixed.

Comment: Is there another way? I only have bluetooth keyboards.

Comment: I plugged in a USB mouse upon wake and it didn't register. It took about five seconds. So the problem is the USB bus right? Is there any documentation online I should be following? Or is it an easy fix, by taking it to an Apple store?